# OTA Update programmatically in android

Tags: android

I have a custom ROM. I want to do **OTA update**. I followed these docs:
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota

https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/apis/update

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bootable/recovery/+/master/updater_sample/

In the sample code, it contains a class called UpdateEngineErrorCodes.
It `imports` the class `UpdateEngine`

```
import android.os.UpdateEngine
```

it shows no class name inside that package.

I'm using an android studio to develop this project:

```
compileSdkVersion 27,
minSdkVersion 21,
targetSdkVersion 27
```

Please help me.

Comment: As far as I can tell, if you use a custom rom you can forget about OTA updates, they are supported only in stock ROMs.

Comment: @HedeH, I meant I want to do a delta update.That update file stored in my server.And this executing process will do in my app,that is installed in this os

Answer (score 0):

UpdateEngine works only with AB update and not with NON-AB update. Your ROM should support that. Here is the link https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/ab

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.